# Applying UK student visa while on visitor visa in the US?

Tags: united-kingdom, indian-citizens, study

I am an Indian citizen came to America for visiting 2 months. I want to apply for UK student visa from America itself. Is it possible? or Do I have to apply only from India?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately NO you cannot apply for a student visa from the USA where you are just a visitor.

Per [Guidance ECB05: : Where to Apply](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy)

> 1. Applications for visit visas and EEA family permits
>
> You can make applications **for a visit visa or EEA family permit** in
> any visa application centre, British diplomatic mission or consular
> post overseas where entry clearance applications are accepted.
>
> 2. Applications for other entry clearance
>
> Applications for other types of entry clearance (except for Tier 5)
> **should be made in your country of residence**. If you have permission to stay in a country as a visitor for 6 months, for
> example, you are **not a resident**.